# Jasperreports: how to gracefully handle or ignore SQL error?

Tags: jasper-reports

Our runtime environment is Tomcat with thin jasperreports servlet with `compile/get` `connection/fill/generate PDF` functionality.
Reports usually consist of several tables, each with its own dataset (SQL query).
JR version is 6.2.0.

Is there a way to:

1. gracefully handle SQL error in a dataset - ie. to catch it and to
   display error code/message

or

2. ignore SQL error so that report execution doesn't get interrupted
   (of course, if other report parts depend on erroneous sql query,
   report will break eventually)

Is it possible to do this using custom scriptlet class, custom data adapter, datasource or something like that (overriding some engine `class/method`)?

With regards,
Goran

Comment: Why should there be errors in the dataset? Could you elaborate what kind of errors you could get?

Comment: Those are not typical `select col1, col2, ... from table1, table2 where ...` datasets. Both `select` and `from` clauses involve many custom functions which can raise exception due to business rules. Eg. function getBatchSize(batch_id) can fail with error "ORA-20194: Batch is not completed" and stop report execution (that is what we are trying to avoid). Exception should be somehow caught and displayed in the report. Of course, we could develop some new functions like isBatchCompleted(batch_id) and use them in SQL but this would add too much complexity.

Answer (score 0):

JasperReport is only a viewer on data. Error management must be done elsewhere.

Two ideas: Materialize the functions into a "business" table and select with JasperReports on the table. Results in more tables, of course. If a job isn't finished yet, there won't be any data. This is the way we usually tackle this requirement.

Or you could use the [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html), select the data in Java code and handle the errors there. In the report you could use the "No data" field or an "Error" parameter, which is usually empty. If an error happens, it will be filled with the error message. This could be done with a `Custom data source`, as seen in [the documentation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#datasources). In the custom data source you can select the data using your own methods and handle any errors. Then you can control the results given back.

*Note:* We haven't implemented a custom data source yet, so there still might be a better way.